# Chaining unary operators with megaparsec

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

I have written a parser using megaparsec for a very simple language consisting of integer literals and two unary operators "a" and "b":

```
data ValueExpr = OpA ValueExpr  
               | OpB ValueExpr
               | Integer Integer

valueExpr :: Parser ValueExpr
valueExpr = makeExprParser valueTerm valueOperatorTable

valueTerm :: Parser ValueExpr
valueTerm = parenthesised valueExpr
          <|> Integer <$> integerLiteral

integerLiteral :: Parser Integer
integerLiteral = -- omitted

valueOperatorTable :: [[Operator Parser ValueExpr]]
valueOperatorTable = [[unaryOp "a" AOp,
                       unaryOp "b" BOp]]

parenthesised :: Parser a -> Parser a
parenthesised = between (char '(') (char ')')

unaryOp :: Text -> (a -> a) -> Operator Parser a
unaryOp name f = Prefix (f <$ symbol name)

binaryOp :: Text -> (a -> a -> a) -> Operator Parser a
binaryOp name f = InfixL (f <$ symbol name)
```

However, it seems that this doesn't allow me to "chain" unary operators, i.e. when trying to parse "ab1", I'm met with "unexpected 'b'". Why is that?

Comment: Without knowing megaparsec's implementation or rationale, I would venture that this is sort of how unary operators are supposed to work, no? I've never seen anybody write `+-5` and expect the result to be "negative five".

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: Why not? E.g. in C I can write `!!2` which will evaluate to `1`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I just tried this in five languages (Ruby, Python, JavaScript, Java and Haskell). In four out of five, the result of evaluating `+-5` is indeed "negative five". In Haskell it's a syntax error because there is no unary `+` operator (so just `+5` would be an error too). If it were, I would expect the result to be negative five in Haskell as well.

Comment: Your definition for `valueTerm` looks off - did you mis-transcribe it? I'd expect it to end with `Integer <$> integerLiteral`, not `Integer <|> integerLiteral`.

Comment: @amalloy: Ah yes, that's a typo, `integerLiteral` is also missing. I removed some stuff to make the example smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is briefly mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.27/parser-combinators-1.2.1/Control-Monad-Combinators-Expr.html#v:makeExprParser) for `makeExprParser`:

> Unary operators of the same precedence can only occur once (i.e., `--2` is not allowed if `-` is prefix negate).  If you need to parse several prefix or postfix operators in a row, ... you can use this approach:
>
> ```
> manyUnaryOp = foldr1 (.) <$> some singleUnaryOp
> ```
>
> This is not done by default because in some cases allowing repeating prefix or postfix operators is not desirable.

In your specific example, something like the following ought to work:

```
valueOperatorTable :: [[Operator Parser ValueExpr]]
valueOperatorTable = [[Prefix unaryOps]]

unaryOps :: Parser (ValueExpr -> ValueExpr)
unaryOps = foldr1 (.) <$> some (OpA <$ symbol "a" <|> OpB <$ symbol "b")
```